# Jquery $.ajax, msg is empty when I call a web service (WCF) method

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have a Web service WCF and I call the methods of my Wcf with Jquery ajax.

When I tested with a method without parameter, it works well.

But when I call a method with parameter, it doesn't work.

The problem is that in my success in $.ajax, msg is empty.

Here is my javaScript code :

```
function getStatistic3() {

var response;
var allstat3 = [];
var allyearstat3 = [];

var kla = $('#Select1').val();
kla = kla.replace("'", "\\'");
if (kla) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:52768/Service1/Statistic_3',
        data: "klant='" + encodeURIComponent(kla) + "'",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            response = msg;
            for (var i = 0; i < response.Items.length; i++) {
                var j = 0;
                allstat3[i] = [response.Items[i].Interventie, response.Items[i].Sum[j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j], response.Items[i].Sum[++j]];
            }
            allyearstat3[0] = [response.Items[0].YearStart, response.Items[0].YearStart + 1, response.Items[0].YearStart + 2, response.Items[0].YearStart + 3, response.Items[0].YearStart + 4];
            fillDataTable3(allstat3, allyearstat3);
            if (bool3) {
                $('thead tr th:eq(0)').replaceWith(function () {
                    return $("<td />").append($(this).contents());
                });
                $('thead th').attr('scope', 'col');
                bool3 = false;
            }
            $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' });
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error loading statistic 3");
        }
    });
}
}
```

I tested all with an .asmx Web service and all works well.

I have this error when I call the method :

```
TypeError: response.Items[0] is undefined
```

[image]

Msg is empty :

[image]

I think that I have a problem when I pass the parameter in ma $.ajax.

Comment: Have you installed `fiddler` or `charles` or `wireshark`?

Comment: Well? Is there a response on the wire? Does it disappear at the application layer? "The problem is that in my success in $.ajax, msg is empty." suggests a MAJOR bug in firefox. Does your code hit your break points in your asmx?

Comment: @Aron, I edited my post. You can see when I debug that "msg" is empty. In my asmx, it works well, but here in WCF, I have this problem.

Comment: We must be looking at different things then, because I see msg is clearly an object with a null ErrorMessage false ErrorOccured, empty Items and MbRecords = 0. There is clearly a bug in your code when the array Items returned is empty. As for why it is empty, that would involve debugging your asmx. PS good effort on translating everything into English.

Comment: Yes, they are the properties of my object but the problem is that I have nbRecord = 0 and I should retrieve data. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: nbRecord = 0 means nothing to me. I don't know your domain objects. However it is clear that line 238 could not run if `Items.length === 0`. You need to have some extra code to deal with zero records returning SPECIFICALLY.

Comment: In my asmx, I have this : 'response = msg.d;' and here (WCF) 'response = msg;'. When I test a method without parameter, it works well. The problem is when I pass a parameter.

Comment: Either your asmx is buggy and returning an empty set wrongly OR your javascript ON LINE 238 `response.Item[0]` is failing because you didn't code it to HANDLE an empty set. THAT IS YOUR PROBLEM. POSSIBLY BECAUSE YOU ARE USING `$.ajax({ data : {klant : kla}})` incorrectly.

Comment: Yes I suspected that the problem was there. Thank you.